# Powershell popup to close applications

Tags: powershell

I want to create powershell file that will create a popup to warn someone that an application will close automatically in 15 mins unless they extend a session.  It should then kill the application unless they extend the session.

I’m completely new to this and this is all I have mustered trying it with the notepad application.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework

$ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNoCancel

$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Error
$MessageBody = "Can we close notepad?"
$MessageTitle = "Using Notepad"

$Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody, $MessageTitle, $ButtonType, $MessageIcon)

Write-Host "Your choice is $Result"

Get-Process Notepad |   Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null }
```

Comment: You are missing the check `if($Result = [System.Windows.MessageBoxResult]::Yes) { ...`. Additionally, I would recommend that you check if there are any processes before you show the dialog.   Your code appears to do what you need. What is the problem?

Comment: While it comes up with a popup with options it is not dependent on what is selected.  Thus regardless of what I press, it will close notepad down.  I want it so that if I say no it doesn’t close notepad but if I say yes it will close it and if I do nothing it will kill it after x amount of time

Comment: It will close regardless, because you do not check if the user clicked `Yes` or not.. Only start the closing code if that is the case. See the first sentence of @Sarin 's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Mathias, if you change this to a switch it works like you want where it takes Yes to close the window, but No and cancel leave it open

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework

$ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNoCancel

$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Error
$MessageBody = "Can we close notepad?"
$MessageTitle = "Using Notepad"

$Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody, $MessageTitle, $ButtonType, $MessageIcon)

switch($Result){
    "Yes" {
        write-host "You selected $Result"
        Get-Process notepad |   Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null } | Stop-Process -Force
    }
    "No" {
        Write-Host "You selected $Result"
    } 
    "Cancel" {
        Write-Host "You selected $Result"
    } 
}
```